# PyQt QTreeview not displaying first column of QAbstractItemModel when built with Qt Designer

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I have built a `Tree` with `QAbstractItemModel` and test it with the code:

```
tree = TreeItem()
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle("plastique")
model = TreeModel(tree)
treeView = QtGui.QTreeView()
treeView.show()
treeView.setModel(model)
```

The creted `tree` is correct (shown in figure below).

[image]

When I try to use the `Tree` in my application in `QTreeVeiw`, built with `Qt Designer` it only shows the second column - `Typeinfo` (shown in figure below). Actually the first column is not seen at the begining, but then if I pull the left edge of column `Typeinfo` to the right the first column is shown, but there are no `tree` lines displayed.

[image]

With the code below, the `TreeView` is created:

**tree_view_widget.py**

```
class TreeViewWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, tree=None, parent=None, flags=0):
        super(TreeViewWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        model = TreeModel(tree)
        self.ui.treeView.setModel(model)
```

**tree_view_widget_ui.py**

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.setEnabled(True)
        Form.resize(200, 300)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 300))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setMargin(0)
        self.gridLayout.setHorizontalSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.treeView = QtGui.QTreeView(Form)
        self.treeView.setEnabled(True)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setKerning(False)
        self.treeView.setFont(font)
        self.treeView.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.treeView.setLineWidth(1)
        self.treeView.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.treeView.setAutoScrollMargin(16)  # 16
        self.treeView.setTabKeyNavigation(True)
        self.treeView.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.treeView.setDragDropOverwriteMode(True)
        self.treeView.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.treeView.setAutoExpandDelay(-1)
        self.treeView.setIndentation(0)
        self.treeView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.treeView.setUniformRowHeights(True)
        self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeView.setAnimated(False)
        self.treeView.setAllColumnsShowFocus(True)
        self.treeView.setHeaderHidden(False)
        self.treeView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("treeView"))
        self.treeView.header().setDefaultSectionSize(0)
        self.treeView.header().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.treeView.header().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeView, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Tree View", None))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
self.treeView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
```

To:

```
 self.treeView.setRootIsDecorated(True)
```

Comment: Or do not set it at all because True is the default.